# Changing color of listbox items in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a listbox for a Windows Phone 7 app that displays info parsed from an XML feed.
I would like to be able to change the color of the font in the listbox, depending on the values parsed from the XML feed. I have searched and can't quite find exactly what I am looking for. Here is the code I have:

```
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("station"))
{
    if (item.Element("name").Value == dest)
    {
     listBox1.Items.Add(item.Element("name").Value);
     listBox1.Items.Add("Last Updated:");
     listBox1.Items.Add(item.Element("date").Value);
     listBox1.Items.Add(item.Element("time").Value);

         foreach (var item1 in item.Descendants("eta"))
         {
          listBox1.Items.Add(item1.Element("destination").Value);
          listBox1.Items.Add(item1.Element("estimate").Value);
         }//foreach

    }//if
}//outer foreach
```

What I want is, for example,

```
if item.Element("name").Value="Fremont" and item1.Element("destination").Value="Daly City", 
then listBox1.Items.Add(item1.Element("destination").Value);
```

will display green color text, for example (and so on for different values of "name" and "destination"). Most of the examples I found were for WPF or something else other than WP7.

Comment: Amanda_Panda do you live in the Dallas area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way *based on what you already have*, is to probably add `ListBoxItem` objects to the listbox instead of just string values.

then you could set `ListBoxItem.Foreground` and other properties.

```
// psuedocode, but reasonably close?
var lbi = new ListBoxItem { Content = item.Element("name").Value };
if (yourcondition)
    lbi.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
listBox1.Items.Add(lbi);
```

While this does work, McAden's answer is *ideally more correct*, in that you should really look into using DataBinding and Templates and stuff instead of doing all this work in code/codebehind.  They'll make your life **much** easier in the future!

Comment: Brushes.Green is getting red squiggly underlined, saying Brushes doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: following the logic of this answer:

    lbi.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

Answer (score 1):

This answer is using DataBinding which it doesn't look like you're using but you can expose `doc.Descendants("station")` as a property and bind the listbox to it. Then, define the DataTemplate for the listbox items to display which portion of the field you want displayed. For the color you can then bind the `Foreground` to the item and define a converter to convert the item to return what color it should be.

Comment: i agree that this is the *more correct* way to do it, so i'm upvoting yours even though mine is marked correct.  In this specific case, it was easier to make my suggestion than to suggest learning data binding :)